# Is Android double-tap-zoom animation or multi-step zooming?

Tags: android, animation, zooming, android-view

Does anyone know the double-tap-zoom function on normal Android application (like web view or image view) is accomplished by zoom animation or by dividing the zoom into small steps and perform them one by one?

If using zoom animation, since animation is cached drawing, is there any problem when I do zoom in like this?

```
mView.zoomTo(newScale);
mView.startAnimation(zoomInAnimation);
```

Should I only set the new scale after animation finished?

And if using multiple steps of zooming, is this really a good approach? How to perform each step? Send messages multiple times?

What is exactly the best way of doing smooth zoom in/out when double tapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend Animation class and override applyTransformarion method, use interpolatedTime parameter to compute the current zoom level

EDIT
as simple as it can be, works with really ancient droids:

```
public class ZoomAnimation extends Animation {
    private float mFrom;
    private float mTo;

    public ZoomAnimation(float from, float to) {
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float currentZoom = mFrom + ((mTo - mFrom) * interpolatedTime);
        // do something with currentZoom
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some sample? And is this approach available on low API levels(8)?

Comment: Thanks! This is really what I want. However, you forgot to specify the duration of the animation, I tried with 200ms it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the best answer, I tried "multiple-step-zooming" by myself, and it turns out charming.

If anyone could give out a better answer, I will accept yours.

The multiple-step-zooming is performed by posting the nested Runnable instance, the **mCanvasScale** is the field used to control the drawing of the view. **setZoomValue()** is setting the mCanvasScale and call invalidate().

```
public void smoothScaleTo(final float targetScale) {
    if(targetScale != mCanvasScale) {
        post(new SmoothScaleExecutor(mCanvasScale, targetScale));
    }
}

private class SmoothScaleExecutor implements Runnable {
    public static final int SMOOTH_SCALE_STEPS = 4;

    private float mStartingScale;
    private float mTargetScale;
    private float mScaleStep;

    public SmoothScaleExecutor(float startingScale, float targetScale) {
        mStartingScale = startingScale;
        mTargetScale = targetScale;
        mScaleStep = (targetScale - startingScale) / SMOOTH_SCALE_STEPS;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mStartingScale < mTargetScale) {
            if(mCanvasScale < mTargetScale) {
                float f = mCanvasScale + mScaleStep;
                if(f > mTargetScale) f = mTargetScale;
                setZoomValue(f);
                post(this);
            }
        } else {
            if(mCanvasScale > mTargetScale) {
                float f = mCanvasScale + mScaleStep;
                if(f < mTargetScale) f = mTargetScale;
                setZoomValue(f);
                post(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```